# Iterating over large line separated file without freezing

Tags: python, graph

I'm trying to implement a Strongly Connected Graph search algorithm and am trying to load a large file with edges of the graph into memory to do it.

The file comes as:

> 1 2 // i.e. a directed edge from 1 to 2
>
> 1 3
>
> 2 3
>
> 3 1
>
> ...

For this part of the algorithm I need to reverse the graph, and I am hoping to store each node in a dictionary along with some other values which will be important for the algorithm.

This code works for smaller files but just stalls/hangs for my large file, which is 72.7mb, I would appreciate any suggestions to make it work on large files:

```
def begin():
    graph = {}
    for line in open('/home/edd91/Documents/SCC.txt'):
        tempArray = []
        for e in line.split():
            if e != ' ' and e!='\n':
                tempArray.append(int(e))            
        if tempArray[1] in graph.keys():
            graph[tempArray[1]]['g'].append(tempArray[0])
        else:
            graph[tempArray[1]] = {'g': [tempArray[0],], 's': False, 't': None, 'u': None }
    print len(graph)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save some time by getting `tempArray` at once for each line and unpacking, if, of course, each line consists of a pair of numbers, and also use a `defaultdict`:

```
import collections

graph = collections.defaultdict(lambda: {'g': [], 's': False, 't': None, 'u': None })
for line in ... :
    k, v = map(int, line.split())
    graph[v]['g'].append(k)
```

Comment: Hi Israel, thanks very much, your answer seems to solve it and I've learnt about defaultdict although don't fully understand the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Not much to be done, but since it's a little too complex, speed suffers.
You can improve the program speed like this:

```
def begin():
    graph = {}
    for line in open('/home/edd91/Documents/SCC.txt'):
        # consider only first 2 fields: avoids the loop and the append: that's the best saver
        # there must not be 2 spaces between the numbers (in your original program neither so not a problem)
        tempArray = line.split()  
        v1 = tempArray[1]  # copy to get rid of array
        if v1 in graph:  # no need to use .keys()
            graph[v1]['g'].append(tempArray[0])
        else:
            graph[v1] = {'g': [tempArray[0],], 's': False, 't': None, 'u': None }
    print len(graph)
```

You can compare speed vs your original program with a medium-sized file first.

Comment: will be faster for sure, but not sure it "solves" it. You can link your big input file (compressed) if you want, I'll have a deeper look. Also, what is the maximum value that tempArray[1] can have? Because maybe graph dictionary could be avoided, replaced by a simple indexed list initialized with `None`. Would save some unnecessary hashing.

Comment: Thanks for your help thus far, I've implemented your changes but unfortunately it still just hangs. Here is a link to the file https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28024296/SCC.txt.tar.gz The largest number is 875714

Comment: I could run my code in 13 seconds (python 3.4) on my PC: `len(graph) = 714547`. Your code, unaltered took 16 seconds and gave the same result... Can you show us the rest of your code?

Comment: I have a thought: can you copy your input file in `/tmp` and run it using this input (local disk)? I'm suspecting a slow/networked filesystem. In which case I can propose something better, but first please test that.

Comment: Hi Jean-Francois, thanks for your help. I managed to get this part of the code working using Israel's suggestion above, but I'm very interested that the code works on your computer and not mine! Maybe it's a architecture problem? I'm running Ubuntu on an Intel Core i5-4460 with 7gb RAM

Comment: Yeah  Israel's solution is just a step ahead of my optimizations. I admit I thought about it but was too lazy to figure out the lambda part at 1 AM :) I honestly don't know why it works for you and my solution doesn't just because of a defaultdict usage! and don't forget your original solution was slow but okay! I'm using windows 10 laptop core i5, not sure how much ram but not a lot, and python 3.4. The version of python used could make a difference.